# OpenCL - local memory over multiple kernels

Tags: memory, local, opencl, gpu

Is it possible, to generate some kind of data on GPU, store it in the local memory and use this data over more than one kernel?

It would be nice to see a simple example, if it's possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just create a buffer in global memory and write into it from your first kernel, and then just read the buffer in your second kernel execution.

Comment: that's the thing i want to avoid, i will write the GPU-generated data in the local memory of the device, cause i've read that this would be faster und cause the GPU-generated data is never used by the Host-Application itself.

Comment: @Soxda2 Global memory is on the Device, local memory is just memory accessible only by each workgroup.